# how can I change the category and url structure?

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, product-urls, category-listing

How can I change the magento 2 url structure ?

For categories I would like:

```
Bike
Bike/Shoes
Bike/Shoes/Mens
etc....
```

for products I would like the product name i.e

```
/etnies-cyprus-scw-x-32-shoes-2018.html
```

Currently Im adding rewrite rules for categories, but I have 1000's

Can this be done programatically or maybe there is already a module I can purchase?

Thanks.

Comment: Dont you think thats default?.. For products you just need to stop categories in url structure. You can do it from configuration->catalog->catalog->SEO->Use Categories Path for Product URLs...And set .html in product url suffix. And i think by default category urls are like that

Comment: obviously not when the urls are similar to: /catalog/category/view/s/snowboard-bindings/id/309/

Comment: Ohh..so you just need to save the category. Magento generates url rewrites when you save the category.